# postgresql could not properly start exited with active (exited)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-10

I installed posgresql from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04) and in the end of installation prints the below command in terminal

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l logfile start
```

I tried to run it with `sudo root` user and also with switching to `postgres` user but gives me below error

> waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: 1: cannot create logfile:
>   Permission denied stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server
>   but when i check the status it says 
>   ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-05-31 13:11:18 UTC;
>   56s ago  Main PID: 3698 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>       Tasks: 0 (limit: 2362)    CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
>
> May 31 13:11:18 staging systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04): Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS... May
>   31 13:11:18 staging systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04): Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

Status is not running except is `exited`.what the above command do and how can i run it ? I haven't faced it in previous versions

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you supply your actual log file instead of `logfile`, but I recommend that you configure logging properly in `postgresql.conf` and use `pg_ctl` without the `-l` option.

- Set `logging_collector` to `on`.
- Set `log_filename` to `postgresql-%a.log`.
- Set `log_rotation_size` to 0.
- Set `log_truncate_on_rotation` to `on`.

Then you'll get the log files in the `log` subdirectory of your PostgreSQL data directory, and they will be rotated on a weekly basis.

Comment: but what this command does and why sudo isn't working. are saying that after your mentioned procedure I don't need to run the above command ?

Comment: You obviously are in a directory where you don't have write permission, hence the error message. If you configure logging like I recommended, you still need to start the server with `pg_ctl`, but you don't need to use the `-l` option any more.